# Delete event for a FileChooserDialog

Tags: dialog, gtk, pygtk, filechooser

i'd like to hide a FileChooserDialog when i delete its window.
I can just hide it from the the 'Cancel' Button but when i close it from its window it doen't respond and then it crashes.

[View the crash here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BQWSeS41)

> The crash happens when i do this, in sequence:
>
> - I open it (it works fine)
> - I try to close it from the window 'X' button: the buttons 'OK' and 'CANCEL' disappear and FileFilter too
> - I re-try to close it. Now the window become white: it seems it doesn't respond.
> - I re-try to close it. It is closed.
> - I try to re-open the FileChooserDialog just closed. It doesn't work anymore and the shell now tells me what it's wrong.

My code is simple:

```
self.__apri_FileChooserDialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(title='', \
                                                                parent=None, \
                                                                action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN, \
                                                                buttons=(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, \
                                                                Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

self.__salva_FileChooserDialog.connect("delete-event", self.nascondi)

def nascondi(self, widget, args=()):
        widget.get_window().hide_on_delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def nascondi(self, widget, args=()):
        widget.get_window().hide_on_delete()
```

For some reason you get the GdkWindow of the dialog widget here, and try to call a method that GdkWindow does not have. That cannot work...

In any case `hide_on_delete()` is, as far as I know, a bit useless in python (because the number of arguments does not match the signal). Fortunately doing it yourself is not difficult. Try this:

```
def on_delete_event (widget, event):
    widget.hide()
    return True

self.__salva_FileChooserDialog.connect("delete-event",
                                       on_delete_event)
```

Comment: 2 errors, maybe the best one is: I was connecting the event to the wrong FileChooserDialog :|